# Can't install libopenssl-ruby

Tags: apt, dpkg, repository, ruby, rails

I'm trying to install ruby on rails and I can't seem to install libopenssl-ruby. I'm on a VPS and I've installed Jaunty as the newer releases don't seem to work very nicely. When I do:

```
apt-get install libopenssl-ruby
```

I get:

```
E: Package libopenssl-ruby has no installation candidate
```

Originally it simply said that it couldn't find the package but after wget'ing a deb form here: http://linuxappfinder.com/package/libopenssl-ruby and trying to install using dpkg I get this new error. Dpkg itself said that it couldn't install my deb as it depended on 'libopenssl-ruby'.

Currently my sources.lst is this:

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy main restricted universe    multiverse
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jaunty is not recommended for a VPS, it's not a LTS release and not supported anymore (which means that there are no security updates!).

Your `sources.list` contains a reference to Hardy, but your system is Jaunty. Replace `hardy` by `jaunty` in your `sources.list` and run `sudo apt-get update` after.

Comment: This also didn't work. Do you think installing a newer version would be best?

Comment: Yes, and because your machine is a server, I recommend to install 10.04 LTS (Long Term Supported) instead of 10.10).

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing **libruby-extras**. It's description says it contains some libraries, including openssl. Isn't that what you are looking for?

EDIT: Further investigation shows out that libruby-extras depends on libopenssl-ruby1.8, while this one is included in libruby1.8 (at least in maverick, but should be similar at older ubuntus) - so it seams you may have already installed the library you are looking for with libruby (if you have libruby) installed.

Comment: This also doesn't appear to exist according to my current settings.

Comment: The edit didn't help either. I do have libruby installed but I'm trying to install passenger and it tells me that its definitely not installed.

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu 14.04, use libopenssl-ruby1.9 instead. e.g.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby1.9
```